# Laravel 5 - Middleware always restricts access while being logged in

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, middleware

I've got a quite annoying problem at the moment :( hope you can help me out there ...

I'm using the basic login form of laravel at the moment with a pretty much untouched User model.
So, the logging in apparently works (tracked it), but whenever I try to restrict content access (restrict routes) with the help of a middleware, it denies the access.

So, why does it deny me the access if I'm apparently logged in?

I'm really not seeing what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for your help in advance! (for further information I copied you my middleware, authcontroller and my user model)

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;


class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{

  use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

  /**
   * The database table used by the model.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $table = 'user';


  /**
   * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

  public $timestamps = false;

  /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $fillable = ['user_properties_ID', 'email', 'password'];

}
```

I'm also using the standard AuthController

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller {

  /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Registration & Login Controller
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
  | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
  | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
  |
  */

  use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

  /**
   * Create a new authentication controller instance.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard  $auth
   * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar  $registrar
   * @return void
   */
  public function __construct(Guard $auth, Registrar $registrar)
  {
    $this->auth = $auth;
    $this->registrar = $registrar;

    // $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout', 'getLogin']);
  }

}
```

And my middleware looks like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated {

    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new filter instance.
     *
     * @param  Guard  $auth
     * @return void
     */

    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }


    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
    if (! $this->auth->check())
    {
      // return $next($request);
      return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
      // return redirect()->intended();
      // return new RedirectResponse(url('/trainingsplan-hinzufuegen'));
    }

    return $next($request);
    }

}
```

routes.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Home
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

Route::group(['prefix' => '', 'middleware' => 'guest', 'namespace' => 'Modules\TrainaryCore\Http\Controllers', 'as' => 'home'], function()
{
  Route::get('/home', 'TrainaryCoreController@render');
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Registrierung
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

Route::group(['prefix' => '', 'namespace' => 'Modules\TrainaryCore\Http\Controllers', 'as' => 'registrieren'], function()
{
  Route::get('/registrieren', 'TrainaryCoreController@render');
  Route::post('/registrieren', 'RegistrationController@validateForm');
});


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Trainingsplan
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

Route::group(['prefix' => '', 'middleware' => 'guest', 'namespace' => 'Modules\TrainaryCore\Http\Controllers', 'as' => 'schedule'], function()
{
  Route::get('/trainingsplan-hinzufuegen', 'TrainaryCoreController@render');
  Route::post('/trainingsplan-hinzufuegen', 'ScheduleController@validateForm');
});
```

Comment: Where are you applying your access restrictions? routes.php or inside a Controller? Include that code too.

Comment: inside the routes.php, added the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, Laravel uses as a standard 'id' for tables ...
so, if you want to rename it you have to add following to your Model:

```
protected $primaryKey  = 'ID';
```

that's the solution boys

Answer (score 0):

Well, what's happening is ok. If you use the GUEST middleware, it'll only allow you in if you are a guest. You gotta use the AUTH middleware.

Comment: First, thanks for helping me, really appreciate it. Problem's only, that this doesn't work either (already tried it), it always redirects me back to the login page, which would mean that I'm not logged in, but I tracked the whole process (including the AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers trait ... If nothing helps I guess I have to implement a custom login

Comment: You've edited the default files as I can see. Is it still failing if you use the default behavior? You've changed the handle method inside RedirectIfAuthenticated and the constructor of AuthController

Comment: I actually reverted all my changes and tried if it works, but it didn't :( there's also a problem when I use the 'auth' Middleware, that it says "too many redirects" and doesn't load the site anymore. I think the problem is if I use this Middleware inside the constructor of the controller it always checks if the user is logged in, even if I'm calling the login page and then redirects again to the login page and so on. I actually do unterstand the Laravel architecture pretty good, but it's probably some little fault after adding some custom stuff ...

Comment: That happens when you get inside a loop. I'd try with a clean install, there's something missing in your reversion.

Comment: i'll give it a shot, thanks for your help! if I discover my fault i'll post it

Comment: well, i reversed all of my changes and apparently it had something to do with my User model ... but can't give you an exact answer here ... it works now though